# Is it possible to set up a USB audio device to look like more than one device?

Tags: usb, audio-streaming

I'm working on a USB audio device based on the iMXRT1060 that currently can be configured as either a 2-spkr/2-mic device or a 6-channel mic-array.  For either case, I can use "arecord -l" (on Linux host) to show the card/device information something like this:

```
card 1: Text [MoreText], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

This works fine, but my goal is to have this device show up as two virtual INPUT devices (device 0: 2-mic and device 1: 6-mic) something like this:

```
card 1: Text [MoreText], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Text [MoreText], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

so that two different Linux programs can use ALSA to connect to the two different input devices independently.  I've been assuming this is mostly just a matter of setting up the descriptor properly but since I haven't been able to do that for a few days, I'm now wondering if I'm trying to do something illegal in USB.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question here...
Apparently as of UAC2, there is the notion of an "Audio Interface Collection".
Below is a snippet from the "USB Device Class Definition for Audio Device" document:

> The collection of the single AudioControl interface and the
> AudioStreaming and MIDIStreaming interfaces that belong to the same
> audio function is called the Audio Interface Collection (AIC). A
> device can have multiple Audio Interface Collections active at the
> same time. These Collections are used to control multiple independent
> audio functions located in the same composite device. An Audio
> Interface Collection is described through the standard USB Interface
> Association mechanism that expresses interface binding via the
> Interface Association Descriptor (IAD).

The IAD is key to making this work, and I can say at this point that the descriptor with two IAD's (and the corresponding AIC) does in fact cause Linux to show two devices in a single audio card.